# Bootstrap-Select doesn't respond to dynamically added rows/content

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select

I have a table row with multiple select boxes on it for form input.

I then can clone that row to create a new row.  Like This.

```
var counter = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addItemRow').click(function() {
          $('#itemMultiInputTable tr:last').clone(true,true).insertAfter('#itemMultiInputTable tr:last');

        $('[id^=item_number]:last').attr('id', 'item_number' + counter);
        $('[name^=item_number]:last').attr('name', 'item_number' + counter);

        $('[id^=select_product]:last').attr('id', 'select_product' + counter);
        $('[name^=select_product]:last').attr('name', 'select_product' + counter);

        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        counter += 1;                   
        return false;                   
    });                                 
});
```

But on the dynamically created rows, any of the 'select' boxes have the select picker box drop down. But when I change the value in the 2nd+ select box, it ONLY changes the value on the FIRST row.

It doesn't matter if its row 2 or 3 or whatever. When I change the selectpicker select box. Only row 1 gets updated.  And rows 2+ always stay at the default value.

Its like they all get tied to the first row, instead of their new (dynamically added) rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: it is always better to create an example for your question in CODEPEN.io or JSFIDDLE.net. Right now, it is difficult to understand the problem as well as trying different hypotheses.

Comment: "item_number" is the beginning of the id you are searching for, so it should be in a single quotation mark, the same with "select_product".

Comment: @zeropoint thanks! I fixed the quotes issue. And I think I've solved it for now, but I'll post a jsfiddle or equivalent in the future as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer, at least that works for me.  It appears I had TWO problems.

1) According to the 'issues' page for bootstrap-select found [here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/605) I learned that bootstrap select adds a div class to replace your select box. You have to remove that class before you can do anything.  Then you have to refresh/reinitialize the bootstrap select on the new rows you have added.

2) Initially after doing all that, I still couldn't get it to work. Turns out it was my clone(true,true). I assumed you wanted to bring the event handlers to the new rows. I guess not. It seems that instead when you clone the event handlers, it ties everything back to the first row.  So changing that to just clone() solved my issues.

For anyone who may run into a similar issue, here is my now functioning code (at least in firefox).

```
var counter = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#addItemRow').click(function() {

      // Fix this clone() part - must NOT be clone(true,true)
      $('#itemMultiInputTable tr:last').clone().insertAfter('#itemMultiInputTable tr:last');

    $('[id^="item_number"]:last').attr('id', 'item_number' + counter);
    $('[name^="item_number"]:last').attr('name', 'item_number' + counter);

    $('[id^="select_product"]:last').attr('id', 'select_product' + counter);
    $('[name^="select_product"]:last').attr('name', 'select_product' + counter);

    // These are the two key lines to making it work
    $('#itemMultiInputTable tr:last').find('.bootstrap-select').replaceWith(function() { return $('select', this); });
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    counter += 1;                   
    return false;                   
 });                                 
});
```

I'll note as well, that this works for all 3 select fields I have in my form. I don't have to address each individually because it just replaces the 'select' fields. And the clone function provides the right data for each field.

I'm self-teaching myself all this as I go, so if anyone notices anything I could do better, I'm always eager to learn.

Thanks.

Comment: That worked, after 4 hours of searching for the solution and making a zombie of javascript + jQuery code your solution finally solved it for me. Thanks!